# How Can I Loop By 5?

Tags: loops, imacros

How can I loop the !var1 by 5?

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !TIMEOUT 2
SET !var1 5808079
ADD !var1 {{!loop}}
```

I want to loop it by 5. How can I do that?

Example:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !TIMEOUT 2
SET !var1 5808079
ADD !var1 {{!loop}}
URL GOTO=facebook/{{!var1}}
```

The output must be:

```
facebook/5808000
facebook/5808005
facebook/5808010
facebook/5808015
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried? You should probably read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that will loop and increment a variable by 5 each time, for more info on using eval check out the iMacros [EVAL](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL) wiki page.

```
VERSION BUILD=7400919 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !VAR2 {{!LOOP}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!VAR2}}\"; var k = s * 5; k;")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

Comment: Your answer fitted my situation. Thank you very much.